# Can't Uninstall SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'm getting an error when trying to uninstall SharePoint Foundation 2010 from Windows 10:

> Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 uninstall did not complete
>   successfully.
>
> One or more required Office components failed to complete
>   successfully.  For more information, consult the setup log file.

Of course, I have no idea where the setup log file is, so I have no idea how to further diagnose what's actually going on.

I tried [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/981228), but it didn't seem to work... I keep getting the same error.

I tried repairing and then removing, I tried using the Uninstall method through Programs and Features, I've looked at several other articles and tried several other fixes... nothing.  I just want a clean install of SP.

Comment: I am surprised you were even able to install SharePoint 2010 on Windows 10. I don't believe it's not even supported. Also, It's never a good idea to pollute your client OS with a beast like SharePoint. The best practice to have a separate VM for these purposes

Comment: I wish that was an option.  But, my company doesn't have any kind of VM software.  I installed it when I started with the company, so I didn't have a whole lot of leeway to tell them what I'm doing.  I've been here 8 months now, so maybe I can get away with that... but, I still gotta get it uninstalled somehow.  I read a thing that it might help to uninstall Office first.  So, I'll try that and report back my findings.

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov - Why would you be surprised that I can install SharePoint 2010 on Windows 10?  Out of Curiosity.

Comment: Actually, I've just checked it. Looks like SP2010 is supported on Windows Server 2012R2 (Win10) started from SP2 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2724471

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov - How does that help me?  Do I need to install a service pack, or...?  I don't have Server 2012.  I can't run the Foundation 2010 installer because it tells me I need a Service Pack for Server 2008.

Comment: Windows 10 is basically the same OS as Windows server 2012R2. Just a client version. Why do you need to uninstall it? Windows 10 has Hyper-V feature built-in. if your edition does not include it, you can always use some free virtualization software like virtual box. it's dirt simple to use

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov - because then I need another Windows license.  I got it uninstalled, but now I can't get it reinstalled because of a server pack missing for 2008 (which I can't install).  I'm trying to create a Dev version of our live site so I can troubleshoot some issues.  I hate SharePoint.  I hate it I hate it I hate it!

Comment: if you have Windows Software Assurace / VDA then you can run a single Windows license as a host and guest on the same machine

Comment: I don't know if I have that. My PM has agreed to commission me a development machine with 2008 R2 JUST for the purpose of debugging and developing in SharePoint. It's just ridiculous that SharePoint is like this.  It shouldn't be this complicated.  SharePoint is a Microsoft product.  It should be SIMPLE SIMPLE SIMPLE to set up a development environment on Microsoft's flagship OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get SharePoint Foundation 2010 uninstalled using Microsoft's magical "uninstall things that are causing problems" utility:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed